# How do i keep my footer on the same line

Tags: css, shopify

I have a shoppify site and the footer it shows the "quick links" "follow us" and the "newsletter" but i want all of them to be on the same page but newsletter keeps going on the next line. here is the code.

```
<div class="clearfix">
      {% if settings.enable_social_links %}
        <h4>{{ settings.footer_social_title }}</h4>
        {% if settings.twitter_link != '' %}<a href="{{ settings.twitter_link }}" title="{{ shop.name }} on Twitter" class="icon-social twitter">Twitter</a>{% endif %}
        {% if settings.facebook_link != '' %}<a href="{{ settings.facebook_link }}" title="{{ shop.name }} on Facebook" class="icon-social facebook">Facebook</a>{% endif %}
        {% if settings.youtube_link != '' %}<a href="{{ settings.youtube_link }}" title="{{ shop.name }} on YouTube" class="icon-social youtube">YouTube</a>{% endif %}
        {% if settings.atom_link != '' %}<a href="{{ settings.atom_link }}" title="{{ shop.name }} news" class="icon-social atom">Blog feed</a>{% endif %}
        {% if settings.instagram_link != '' %}<a href="{{ settings.instagram_link }}" title="{{ shop.name }} on Instagram" class="icon-social instagram">Instagram</a>{% endif %}
        {% if settings.pinterest_link != '' %}<a href="{{ settings.pinterest_link }}" title="{{ shop.name }} on Pinterest" class="icon-social pinterest">Pinterest</a>{% endif %}
        {% if settings.vimeo_link != '' %}<a href="{{ settings.vimeo_link }}" title="{{ shop.name }} on Vimeo" class="icon-social vimeo">Vimeo</a>{% endif %}
        {% if settings.tumblr_link != '' %}<a href="{{ settings.tumblr_link }}" title="{{ shop.name }} on Tumblr" class="icon-social tumblr">Tumblr</a>{% endif %}
        {% if settings.google_link != '' %}<a href="{{ settings.google_link }}" title="{{ shop.name }} on Google+" class="icon-social google">Google+</a>{% endif %}
      {% endif %}
        </div>

        <div class="span4">
      {% if settings.footer_display_newsletter %}
      <div class="p30">
        <h4>{{ settings.footer_newsletter_title }}</h4>
        <form action="{{ settings.mailing_list_form_action }}" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" target="_blank">
          <input type="email" value="" placeholder="Email Address" name="EMAIL" id="mail" /><input type="submit" class="btn newsletter" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="subscribe" />
        </form>
      </div>
      {% endif %}
      </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Can you provide a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) in which you reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 0):

To keep elements on the same line, make them inline-block.

```
.p30, .p30 * { display: inline-block }
```